# SQL Server stored procedure, exec from another query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm learning SQL and I've got some problems calling a stored procedure from a new/different query.

I has build a `installDB.sql` file where there are created some tables and additionally filled these with data.

Furthermore I use a stored procedure as well, to add some functions.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Add_Book
    @User CHAR(50),
    @Book CHAR(50)
    AS
INSERT INTO Relationtable(book_id, user_id, current_dato) 
    VALUES(
        (SELECT book_id FROM Books WHERE book_title = @Book),
        (SELECT user_id FROM Users WHERE user_name = @User),
         GETDATE()
    )
```

In this query (tab) I can `exec` that procedure (without problems):

```
exec Add_Book myUser, myBook
```

But if I try this command in a new query (tab), it doesn't work.

I want the `installDB` to build all my functions and be able to call them later from another queries.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 2
Could not find stored procedure 'Add_Book'... i try to use this code in a new query.
`use Libary exec Add_Book myUser, myBook`.

Comment: The above-mentioned Command is just working inside the `installDB.sql`. Others do not find the `Add-Book`-Function

Comment: When you open the new query tab what is the selected database set to in the drop down list? Is it the correct one?

Comment: oops, it was set on `master`. Recompiled and refresehed and it's working now, for some reason. Excuse me for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

We use this method to setup and maintain databases in our product.  We have many separate SQL scripts that install all the required tables, tempdb tables, views, functions, stored procedures, etc.  Later, when people run code that executes those stored procedures, the procs can be executed like normal.

If this install script is running in a transaction and ends in a `ROLLBACK` or encounters an error, everything installed to that point will fail.  Similarly, if the install script began with a `BEGIN TRAN`, and there was no `COMMIT`, then the procs don't exist yet.

Another possibility is that the install script ran against a different database or different server than you expected.  After running the script, you should be able to execute it in a Microsoft SQL Management Studio query window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds a bit complicated for me as a beginner. So the simple way as I did with `exec Add_Book myUser, myBook` will not work in this case? The goal is just to make 2 scripts, one which can add and one which can delete. This can be easily done like I did above. Disadvantage: The user is able to see the script-code. Therefore I decide to write all functions(stored procedures) in to the `installDB.sql` and only hand off the exec-command.

Comment: Did you put both the `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `DROP PROCEDURE` in the same installDB.sql script?